# will_paginate usage with web call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

my index action calls out to the web

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://www.ask.com/open')
```

I added pagination to the index, because there were too many results

```
@asks = ask.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

and the corresponding call to will_paginate in my view

The problem I have is when the user clicks to move to the next page, it results in the service all being made to the server. I want to just have it fetch the results from model if it is a pagination call, but call the service if the index is being called directly.

Comment: can't you just check if `params[:page]` is present?

Comment: I tried that - however, even a refresh on the page has a params[:page] present

Comment: if you're refreshing the page while you're on the second page, then you will surely get a `params[:page]`